# Manipulate WebAPi POST

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a WebAPI POST controller like the one below:

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(Product))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostProduct(Product product)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Products.Add(product);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = product.Id }, product);
    }
```

To be valid, it expects several values, lets say Name, Price, URL, ManufactureID, StatusID.

However, the POST will not always contain a value for StatusID for example, and therefore the above will fail, as i cannot be null.
But when the value is not sent by the POST, i want to 'intercept' and set the value in code. Let say to int 1.

How would i go about this?

I have been using DTOes for extraxting data from the API, in a nice and viewable way. Can DToes be used in POST also? If so, how? Or any other approach, to setting data, if it does not excist in the POST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say create your Product request model which will be defined in your WebAPI models and there your can define your StatusID as a nullable. After your receive request you can map your Product request data to ProductDto and in that mapping you set your default values if you need them.

Altough you can intercept request on client side and update it but I'm not sure is that something that will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a POST product class that is agnostic of the persistence. Don't use the generated Product class of your ORM. Using your example above, you should have a ProductModel class that will only contain the properties that the API client can update. Then do the mapping of the DTO to your product data model.

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostProduct(ProductModel model)
{
   ...
   var product = db.Products.New();
   //mapping here
   product.Name = model.Name;
   product.Price = model.Price;
}
```